# Opening Excel workbook via code vs dbl clicking

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel file that runs some simulation. It's too complex to post here but it's also not the thing really in question, but what I'm seeing is that if I just dbl click the workbook to open it and then run the simulation (click a button on the workbook) it works fine. However if I use the below code in a C# project to open the workbook and then run the simulation (again just click the button) it gives different results. I'm wondering if anyone knows anything about why anything would be different when you open a workbook via code vs just dbl clicking it to open. I'm completely at a loss and any ideas at all would help a ton. Thanks!

```
private Application oExcel = null;
private Workbooks oBooks = null;
private _Workbook oBook = null;

private void OpenExcelFile(string filename)
{
    oExcel = new Application();
    oExcel.Visible = true;
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
    //oExcel.DisplayAlerts = true;

    oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
    oBook = oBooks.Open(filename);
}
```

I've tried both Microsoft Excel 14.0 and 15.0 Object Library

Comment: How do the results differ?

Comment: This is difficult to answer as the simulation is very complex (I didn't write it and don't know much about it's details) and calls an external DLL to do a lot of it's functionality. I realize this makes it harder to answer but just looking if anyone has ever noticed differences when opening workbooks via code vs dbl clicking and what they figured out the issue was. At some level something must be different in the 2 styles of opening a workbook.

Comment: Perhaps the difference has to do with the 'current directory' being different when opened through C#. If you double-click on an excel file, the current directory would presumably the that of the location of the excel file while that might not be the case when the file is opened as a 'file/open'. Does the simulation use any resources that make assumption as to the current directory? What is the result if you start excel manually, then do a File/Open to open the file, then run the simulation?

Comment: You know what. If I open Excel app then do File-Open and then run the sim I get the errors. Very interesting. So how would I tell excel in code the current working directory as that seems like a good lead.

Comment: Does the simulation rely on any add-ins?  I'm not sure add-ins load when Excel is started via automation.

Comment: You could try setting the DefaultFilePath on the excel application object

Comment: Or perhaps Environment.CurrentDirectory